# Is there bijection between Cayley tables and (finite) groups (if the order of rows and colums doesn't matter)?

Tags: group-theory, cayley-table

I have questions about structure of groups.

Is there bijection between Cayley tables and (finite) groups?

So, Cayley table is a table of permutations of finite elements in which none element repeat in any row and any column. And, so, every group has to satisfy this and thus can be represented as Cayley table.

Edit: I meant bijection between general Cayley table $n$ by $n$ (order of rows and colums doesn't matter) and group with $n$ elements. In on other words, if you give me $m$ by $m$ Cayley table is there unique group with $m$ elements? (Reverse holds because of group properties.)

Comment: If you re-arrange the list of elements you get a different Cayley table for the same group. For a bijection you need to use the appropriate equivalence on both sides (for groups it is isomorphism)

Comment: "Cayley table is a table of permutations of finite elements in which none element repeat in any row and any column."  Most of those tables are not associative.

Comment: An $n\times n$ arrangement of $n$ symbols such that each of them occurs exactly once in each row and in each column is called a [latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square). While all Cayley tables are latin squares, not all latin squares are Cayley tables. By definition, a Cayley table is the "graph" of the multiplication function of a group, so of course every table corresponds to a finite group and vice-versa.